# How to save/store the image in matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

With reference to the example in mathworks "SimpleColorDetector" http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26420-simplecolordetection

Can someone let me know how to save the image 'redObjectsMask' ?

I tried saving it with `imwrite(redObjectsMask,'test.jpg');`

but it is being saved as a black image. 
But on `imshow(redObjectsMask,[]);`

it shows the correct image.

Here is the sample of the code :

```
redMask = (redBand >= redThresholdLow) & (redBand <= redThresholdHigh);
greenMask = (greenBand >= greenThresholdLow) & (greenBand <= greenThresholdHigh);
blueMask = (blueBand >= blueThresholdLow) & (blueBand <= blueThresholdHigh);

redObjectsMask = uint8(redMask & greenMask & blueMask);
    subplot(3, 3, 4);
    imshow(redObjectsMask, []); % this shows the image I require to be saved
    imwrite(redObjectsMask,'test.jpg'); % this saves a blank image
```

Comment: Can you please post a bit of your code and what redObjectsMask looks like? As much as we would like to help you not may people will download and run a function to try and guess the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the empty brackets `[]` as a second argument to `imshow` you **scale** the image intensity for display. You need to do the same for saving the image.

```
redObjectsMask = double( redObjectsMask ); % make sure you work with float type
redObjectsMask = ( redObjectsMask - min(redObjectsMask(:) ) ./ ( max(redObjectsMask(:)) - min( redObjectsMask(:)) );
imwrite( redObjectsMask, 'test.jpg');
```

If you `redObjectsMask` is of logical type, you might solve it in an easier way:

```
redObjectsMask = uint8( redObjectsMask ) * 255; % white is 255 and not 1
imwrite( redObjectsMask, 'test.jpg');
```

Comment: Excellent ! Thanks a lot sir :) It was a logical type one. 
May I know why it doesn't save in the usual method ?

Comment: @Vishal jpg is saved with 8bits per pixel, logical array has values 0 and 1, if you save a pixel with value 1 it is only slightly brighter than a completely dark pixel. "white" is a pixel with value 255 (far from 1).

Comment: @Vishal you might also want to consider saving maps and masks as indexed images. use `>> doc imwrite` for more information.